# How to set default path (route prefix) in express?

Tags: node.js, express

Instead of doing `path + '..'` foreach route - how can I prefix every route?

My route shall be

```
/api/v1/user
```

What I don't want to do

```
var path = '/api/v1';
app.use(path + '/user', user);
```

What I want to do

```
 var app = express();
 app.setPath('/api/v1');
 app.use(..);
```

Comment: Can someone clarify what this question means? It sounds similar to something I'm looking for, but it's not very clear to me what's really being asked for here...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Using Express 4 you can use [`Router`](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#express-router)

```
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/user', user);

app.use('/api/v1', router);
```

Comment: is there also a smart way to handle all redirects wirh a prefix?

Comment: I understand the `router` option, but it is a shame that express doesn't have something like `app.setRootPath(myPath)` I would like to, in my underlying code to be able to set the root path so I only ever need to use the `app` object.

Comment: using `get` makes it clearer I think. e.g `router.get('/user', user);`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Express 4 [`Router`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) you can use route() method to set the path and create a chainable route handler

```
app.route('/book')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book')
  });
```

Comment: Yeah that is correct for a single endpoint/route, but the question requires to have a prefix path for all routes in case there are many and not just one. But this is already covered in the accepted answer. anyway nice to see your perspective.