# Minimizing duplicate routes index.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build a REST API with express router, which contains of nested sub routes. I have mounted these sub routes in my `index.js` file.

I have defined it as follows:

```
// Mounted routes
app.use('/api/v1/Project', new ProjectRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context', new ContextRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context/:contextId/Question', new QuestionRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context/:contextId/Question/:questionId/Answer', new AnswerRouter().routes);
```

I want to arrange my routes revolved around the functionality and being more complaint towards REST standards.

> **In the above case the route prefix `/api/v1/Project/` is being
>   repeated over and over again.**
>
> Is there some best practice to minimize the redundant routes by
>   prefixing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default path (route prefix) in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993660/how-to-set-default-path-route-prefix-in-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem by using the approach detailed in this link [Nested Router in Express.JS](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/f38b208a492e4dcd45f487638eff716c).**

The solution being we have to just mount the nested router in the module as follows:

```
app.use('/:nestedId/nestedRoute', nestedRouter);
```

Furthermore we need to also merge the parent route parameters also, we can do this by passing the `options` object to the `express.Router` method:

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```